# how to convert m4v to image sequence?

Tags: h.264, video-encoding, video-editing, m4v

I am trying to extract frames from m4v files compressed with H264. I am studying the compression artifacts generated by h264 so I actually need the exact frames (re-encoding is not an option). I know that VirtualDub allows me to do this for .avi or .divx files, but doesn't work with m4v files.
Is there a tool that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Maybe try mplayer with `-vf screenshot`. If you just need a few frames, jump to the desired location, pause, and hit the screenshot key. It's possible that you can also use that filter to write out continuous screenshots.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You know, that is what I ended up using. You can do shift+d in smplayer (and I guess shift+s if you do it in linux with -vf screenshot) and just capture frames non-stop as png files, which is great. It accepted all the videos, even those that didn't work with MPEG streamclip.

Comment: Awesome. Always happy to learn new features of mplayer, I've only taken single frames so far :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to extract a longer sequence and MPEG Streamclip doesn't work on your system, you can use ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i input.dv -r 25 -f image2 images%05d.png
```

You may need to replace the 25 with the actual frame rate of the video. I'm not sure if ffmpeg would blend between multiple frames if you set the frame rate to something different than the source frame rate.

More information is avalable at [stream0.org](http://stream0.org/2008/02/06/howto_extract_images_from_a_vi/), where I found it.

Answer (score 1):

One of my favourite video tools is [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/).

I just tried to export the m4v sample [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425) to a sequence of images, and it works.

**UPDATE**

Said tool is only available for Windows and Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it hangs in my computer, even with the example you post. But it did convert a portion of it. Probably I can work around it, this one should do.

Comment: Hangs for me, too :-/